# Set VM property based on a mouse over event in the Xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I would like to set the value of a property in my VM to true once the MouseOver event on a DockPanel is raised. So far no luck with the triggers. Would you have any clue? Thanks

```
<DockPanel.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=MyProperty}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="??" Value="??"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DockPanel.Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

I use the Interactivity namespace `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`
to do things like this ...

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

So now you have triggered a command in the VM based on an event in the view. Obviously the datacontext at this point must be the VM so that `DoSomethingCommand` can be triggered on the VM, but if not then just change it bubble out to a place where the data context *is* the VM ...

e.g.

`Command=(Binding DataContext.DoSomethingCommand , RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid}}`

or whatever kind of element has your VM context.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you assign datacontext to your whole page it would be picked by style as well. 
set something like a class and set property as it's value.

```
  property = {Binding YourDataContext.YournewValue}
```

Comment: My context is actually already set to something else, don't want to change it. Any other option with the code I propose?

Comment: no worries... just add another property to your context and then go like the updated answer